debugging loading an emacs-module problem on Mac
I have written an emacs-module to use a function from the GNU scientific library. It builds and runs fine locally. I am trying to get GitHUB actions to run a test on it though, and that is failing. The problem is it cannot link to the external library:
  find /usr/lib -name "libgsl.so.27"
  pkg-config --cflags gsl
  pkg-config --libs gsl
  cd examples/gsl && make && pwd && ls && make test
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    NIX_PATH: nixpkgs=channel:nixos-unstable
    TMPDIR: /home/runner/work/_temp
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so.27

-lgsl -lgslcblas -lm 
cc -g3 -Og -shared -fPIC -I/nix/store/7d634lfkn191jbalvdm5jdsxf4709dda-emacs-29-4/include/ -I/nix/store/7d634lfkn191jbalvdm5jdsxf4709dda-emacs-29-4/lib/    -c -o gsl-linalg.o gsl-linalg.c
cc -shared -o gsl-linalg.so gsl-linalg.o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm 
/home/runner/work/emacs-ffi/emacs-ffi/examples/gsl
gsl-linalg.c
gsl-linalg.o
gsl-linalg.so
makefile
readme.org
tests.el
emacs -batch -q -l tests.el -f test-linalg
Module could not be opened: "/home/runner/work/emacs-ffi/emacs-ffi/examples/gsl/gsl-linalg.so", "libgsl.so.27: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

I guess this is related to some kind of library path issue in GitHUB actions, but I don't understand how it could compile fine, make the library, and then not be able to link to the external library. That lib definitely exists (at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so.27).
I tried something like export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, but this leads to a new error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjansson.so.4: version JANSSON_4' not found (required by emacs). Apparently there is a specific version at /nix/store/pxwhyhhyfa4q7nv4065b9n5x7xhvi39i-jansson-2.14/lib. If I put this directory first, there is another error: /usr/bin/ld: symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/ld: undefined symbol: json_delete, version libjansson.so.4`.
Seems weird. Any ideas how to fix it?
You can see more detail at https://github.com/jkitchin/emacs-ffi/

What path to libgl.so.27 do you see if you replace the last chain of commands to […old content…] && ls && ldd gsl-linalg.so && make test? (P.S.: I am not sure it's a Emacs question btw, so if you don't get answers here, you might have better luck asking on SO)

This was helpful. I can see it is looking for libgsl.so.27 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so.27 (0x00007f8ca9a00000). It doesn't solve my problem though, when I put that path in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, I get this error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjansson.so.4: version `JANSSON_4' not found (required by emacs). I checked, and that is the version that emacs is linked to also.

I think you need to set up a self-contained environment for testing, perhaps in a container. Otherwise, you end up playing whack-a-mole with every "missing" library.

@NickD the issue here is not a missing library, that part is fine. Something's going on with paths. But yeah, perhaps if Github provides some way to download the CI container locally, I guess that might be the best way to debug the issue, to be able to inspect the system more easily…

I understand that (that's why "missing" is in quotation marks).

There's a hint as part of this CI run. You can see various library paths both for Emacs and the library you just built, so let's break it down.

Module could not be opened: "/home/runner/work/emacs-ffi/emacs-ffi/examples/gsl/gsl-linalg.so", "libgsl.so.27: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

TL;DR of this paragraph: the container has "special" configuration, where ld by default doesn't search system library path.
In more details: the container in question uses Nix package manager. I've never used Nix OS (and from my experience in the context of this answer I don't think I ever will), but from what I know about it they promote paths design where each lib or app is installed to its own unique path under /nix/store/… that includes an id, which allows you to have multiple versions of the same library.
I tried digging in the context of the question, and my impression is that Nix OS apps do not typically access global system paths. Instead they have hardcoded rpaths that point to the exact library locations.
Here it's worth noting that to prove this theory I tried installing nixos/nix container and installing an app inside it. I was horrified how complicated this seemingly simple task. Apparently, you have to write config files to just do that. There's a "search" option, but for some reason it's hidden under "experimental" flag, and I couldn't make it to work.
But good news is I found this post, some folk stumbled upon a problem similar to yours, and it is in particular mentioned in there that rpath is used. So at least that part is proven without jumping through the hoops with awkward Nix OS package management.

I tried something like export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, but this leads to a new error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjansson.so.4: version JANSSON_4' not found (required by emacs)

This error means that library was found but it has the wrong version. That happens because LD_LIBRARY_PATH overrides the order in which libs are searched, so instead of finding specific version located somewhere under /nix/store it gets the one located in system directories.
Solutions

Using another CI image that provides non-NIX-based emacs. I think it's the easiest one, because looking at the blog post I linked in the text about rpaths, making library locations work as you want in this case might turn into an adventure…
I guess you found similar workaround: doing apt-get install emacs to install it past Nix package manager. Though that may take additional time for package installation, unless Github caches steps.

Running with LD_PRELOAD=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so.27:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgslcblas.so.0. Hopefully should work. But it's not ideal because if you ever want to add additional deps, you'll have to remember the idiosyncrasy of this image not finding the libs.

Building your library with -Wl,-rpath parameter that points to the exact locations of the libraries. This is similar to LD_PRELOAD point, just at build time instead of run time. That way your library loading would work similarly to Nix OS emacs loading.



Thanks for the deep dive on what is happening here. Your solution 1 is basically what I did below. Testing the module seems like a special worst case scenario for this!

I have figured out the problem is with using the emacs from purcell/setup-emacs@master in my setup. If I use a regular install of Emacs via apt-get in my GitHUB action yml file I don't have these path problems, and the libraries load fine.

That's interesting. I am using jcs090218/setup-emacs@master on color-identifiers-mode that I co-maintain, you might try it to see if it fixes the problem. That said, the answer doesn't really answer what happens and why, but given it's just your local issue, I guess that's fine, at least it works for you.

NVM my comment on jcs090218's emacs, it's using Purcell's image internally with some additional configuration, so trying it won't change anything.
